# Ring Theory: Identity Elements

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

A brief question$:$ If a ring is specified to have an identity, is it implicit that the identity in question is the multiplicative identity? From the definition of a ring $R$, $R$ must contain additive identity to begin with.

Thanks in advance, I couldn't figure this out from rereading my text.

Comment: Yes, it is. All rings have additive identity always, no matter what the convention is.

Comment: The convention is to say that "$R$ is a ring with $1$", and denote the additive identity by $0$. So it is clear that $1$ is the multiplicative identity.

Comment: Great, thanks for specifying. Unfortunately, the text I am using does not usually specify "$R$ is a ring with $1$."

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes. If a ring $(R, +, \cdot)$ is said to have an identity, that means specifically the identity of $(R, \cdot)$.

As you pointed out earlier, all rings have an additive identity since $(R, +)$ must be a group.

Answer (score 3):

Yes!

By definition, a ring $(R,+,\cdot)$ is a set $R$ with two binary operations $+,\cdot$ (called addition and multiplication) that satisfies eight properties: five of which is that $(R,+)$ is an abelian group (closed, associative, existence of $0$, invertibility of each element, and commutativity), two of which is that $(R,\cdot)$ is a semi-group (closed and associative) and the eighth property is the distributive property.

So, the additional property needs to be that $(R, \cdot)$ has a multiplicative identity. In such cases, we call $(R, \cdot)$ a monoid. [Note: By definition, a monoid is a set which a binary operation that is closed, associative and has an identity element.]